# Location not updating using google maps apiv2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I m struggling for integrating google maps in my app. I have somehow managed to display map with user location and nearby locations but the location is not updating...I have gone through the code several time but havent found a single incorrect command..plz help me sort it out..

NearbyPlacesActivity -

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * MyMapActivity class forms part of Map application
 * in Mobiletuts+ tutorial series:
 * Using Google Maps and Google Places in Android Apps
 * 
 * This version of the class is for the final part of the series.
 * 
 * Sue Smith
 * March/ April 2013
 */
public class NearbyPlacesActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    //instance variables for Marker icon drawable resources
    private int userIcon, foodIcon, drinkIcon, shopIcon, otherIcon;

    //the map
    private GoogleMap theMap;

    //location manager
    private LocationManager locMan;

    //user marker
    private Marker userMarker;

    //places of interest
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    //max
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;//most returned from google
    //marker options
    private MarkerOptions[] places;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_places);

        //get drawable IDs
        userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
        foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
        drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
        otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

        //find out if we already have it
        if(theMap==null){
            //get the map
            theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            //check in case map/ Google Play services not available
            if(theMap!=null){
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //create marker array
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
                //update location
                updatePlaces();
            }

        }
    }

    //location listener functions

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "location changed");
        updatePlaces();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider disabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider enabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "status changed");
    }

    /*
     * update the place markers
     */
    private void updatePlaces(){
        //get location manager
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat+","+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //remove any existing marker
        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();
        //create and set marker properties
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("You are here")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
        .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        //move to location
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        //build places query string
        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=7000&sensor=true" +
                "&types=food|bar|movie_theater|museum|bank"+
                "&key=AIzaSyBqDgqbxFenOtooTivY5YSsJ2JrwBK42hw";//ADD KEY

        //execute query
        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);       
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places

            //build result as string
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data

                    //HTTP Get receives URL string
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    //execute GET with Client - return response
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    //check response status
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //only carry on if response is OK
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //get response entity
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        //get input stream setup
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        //create reader
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        //use buffered reader to process
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
        //process data retrieved from doInBackground
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            //remove existing markers
            if(placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                    if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try {
                //parse JSON

                //create JSONObject, pass stinrg returned from doInBackground
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //get "results" array
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                //marker options for each place returned
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    //if any values are missing we won't show the marker
                    boolean missingValue=false;
                    LatLng placeLL=null;
                    String placeName="";
                    String vicinity="";
                    int currIcon = otherIcon;
                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        //get place at this index
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        //get location section
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location");
                        //read lat lng
                        placeLL = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")), 
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));  
                        //get types
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        //loop through types
                        for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType=types.get(t).toString();
                            //check for particular types - set icons
                            if(thisType.contains("food")){
                                currIcon = foodIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("bar")){
                                currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("movie_theater")){
                                currIcon = shopIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //vicinity
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        //name
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException jse){
                        Log.v("PLACES", "missing value");
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //if values missing we don't display
                    if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                    else
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(placeLL)
                    .title(placeName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                    .snippet(vicinity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=theMap.addMarker(places[p]);

            }

        }
    }   
}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error in logcat. The Manifest is accurate as per my concern...the API keys are also correct..

There is one more thing I want to know....How can I show a particular city's map by clickin on a button of previous activity..for eg: In activity one i typed New York in edittext and clicked button and it opened Activity two containing map and points to New York city...I also want to show the tourist attractions in newyork by different markers.... Can someone show me a way or tut for this..thanks in advance

**This is the Revised code as per your guidance..**

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * MyMapActivity class forms part of Map application
 * in Mobiletuts+ tutorial series:
 * Using Google Maps and Google Places in Android Apps
 * 
 * This version of the class is for the final part of the series.
 * 
 * Sue Smith
 * March/ April 2013
 */
public class NearbyPlacesActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    //instance variables for Marker icon drawable resources
    private int userIcon, foodIcon, drinkIcon, shopIcon, otherIcon;

    //the map
    private GoogleMap theMap;

    //location manager
    private LocationManager locMan;

    //user marker
    private Marker userMarker;

    //places of interest
    private Marker[] placeMarkers;
    //max
    private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;//most returned from google
    //marker options
    private MarkerOptions[] places;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_places);

        //get drawable IDs
        userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
        foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
        drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
        shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
        otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

        //find out if we already have it
        if(theMap==null){
            //get the map
            theMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            //check in case map/ Google Play services not available
            if(theMap!=null){
                //ok - proceed
                theMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                //create marker array
                placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];

            }

        }
    }

    //location listener functions

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "location changed");
        updatePlaces(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider disabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider enabled");
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "status changed");
    }

    /*
     * update the place markers
     */
    private void updatePlaces(Location givenlocation){
        //get location manager
        double lat = givenlocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = givenlocation.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat+","+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //remove any existing marker
        if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();
        //create and set marker properties
        userMarker = theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lastLatLng)
        .title("You are here")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
        .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
        //move to location
        theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

        //build places query string
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String encodedstr = URLEncoder.encode("food|bar|movie_theater|museum|bank");
        String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=7000&sensor=true"+
                "&types="+encodedstr+
                "&key=AIzaSyBqDgqbxFenOtooTivY5YSsJ2JrwBK42hw";//ADD KEY

        //execute query
        new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);       
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
    }

    private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
            //fetch places

            //build result as string
            StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //process search parameter string(s)
            for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
                HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    //try to fetch the data

                    //HTTP Get receives URL string
                    HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                    //execute GET with Client - return response
                    HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                    //check response status
                    StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();
                    //only carry on if response is OK
                    if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        //get response entity
                        HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                        //get input stream setup
                        InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                        //create reader
                        InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                        //use buffered reader to process
                        BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                        //read a line at a time, append to string builder
                        String lineIn;
                        while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            return placesBuilder.toString();
        }
        //process data retrieved from doInBackground
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //parse place data returned from Google Places
            //remove existing markers
            if(placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                    if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                }
            }
            try {
                //parse JSON

                //create JSONObject, pass stinrg returned from doInBackground
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //get "results" array
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                //marker options for each place returned
                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    //if any values are missing we won't show the marker
                    boolean missingValue=false;
                    LatLng placeLL=null;
                    String placeName="";
                    String vicinity="";
                    int currIcon = otherIcon;
                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        //get place at this index
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        //get location section
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry")
                                .getJSONObject("location");
                        //read lat lng
                        placeLL = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")), 
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));  
                        //get types
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                        //loop through types
                        for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType=types.get(t).toString();
                            //check for particular types - set icons
                            if(thisType.contains("food")){
                                currIcon = foodIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("bar")){
                                currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(thisType.contains("movie_theater")){
                                currIcon = shopIcon;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //vicinity
                        vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                        //name
                        placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException jse){
                        Log.v("PLACES", "missing value");
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //if values missing we don't display
                    if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                    else
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(placeLL)
                    .title(placeName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                    .snippet(vicinity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=theMap.addMarker(places[p]);

            }

        }
    }   
}
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(theMap!=null){
            //get location manager
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        updatePlaces(lastLoc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(theMap!=null){
            locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Please have a check on it...it is not updating my location...although its showinng nearby locations..thanks in advance

Comment: just use `theMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);` and you use the map's location listener

Comment: To animate the map to a specific location given a city as a String you may want to look at the Geocoder class, particularly its getFromLocationName().

Comment: i m completely confused guys... I understood wat u r saying @tyczj but can you plz edit my code as i may not do it as perfectly as you will...plz its a request...Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be that  whenever you get a call to `onLocationChanged()`, you are calling `updatePlaces()` method where you are reintialising your location manager. The line `locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` will return a new instance of the location manager and then you are calling `getLastKnownLocation` for this new location manager. Your `getLastKnownLocation` must be returning an outdated location information and hence you may not be seeing any update. You end up using this location instead of the fresh location return by your change listener. 
You can initialise these and call updatePlaces in onResume like below :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(theMap!=null){
            //get location manager
        locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //get last location
        Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);
        updatePlaces(lastLoc)
        }
    }
```

Modify locationchanged:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.v("MyMapActivity", "location changed");
        updatePlaces(location);
    }
```

Modify updateplaces:

```
private void updatePlaces(Location givenlocation){

        double lat = givenlocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = givenlocation.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lat+","+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //create LatLng
        LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

    *****Call further steps using the above location ******
```

Currently you are using the location API that is part of android platform . I would also suggest you can migrate to the new [The Google Location Services API, part of Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) as it handles location updates and battery conservation in an improved manner.

Comment: what should I pass in the updatePlaces() when it is being called from the oncreate method... This is the only error showin in the code..

Comment: dont call in onCreate. the first call in onResume is enough as onResume will always be called after an onCreate call.

Comment: ohk...thanks... wish I had a bounty to give you...your answer is worth a 50+ bounty

Comment: Now i got into another prob...actually my map was showing nearby food type places but when I entered some more types in the place search string for eg: &types=food|bar|movie_theater|museum|bank"+ , It wasnt showing any of them...wats the matter with it..

Comment: String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
    "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
    "&radius=7000&sensor=true" +
    "&types=food|bar|movie_theater|museum|bank"+
    "&key=mykey";

Comment: please do some check on the observation you are seeing for the places api, especially if there is any limit on the max number of types in a search. if you are still facing an issue, i suggest that you can post it as a separate question with google-places-api category. for the location update issue, please check if it resolved and then accordingly comment and acknowledge the answer

Comment: location update is showing my current position...but nearby places are still not available..and I havent added any max no. of types restriction in my search.. U can go through the code that I have posted previously..do u find anything wrong with the markers or fetching nearby places ....coz the place search query that I have framed is correct as I tested it as a url and it displayed status:OK and showed couple of fetched results..

Comment: the changes you asked me to do doesnt affectd at all...should i repost the edited version of the code...I took care of each and every change that you mentioned but still i m not getting the updated location...i m not getting where the problem is occuring....